# Disable text selection by click start

Tags: javascript, jquery, textselection

I know I can [disable text selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting) for a div but that is not what I want.

I have this [jquery color picker](http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/) and as you can see on the webpage in the flat example, if you pick a color keep the mouse pressed and move all over the page nothing get's selected. That is what I want but somehow it does not work in my example:

http://jsfiddle.net/x6sAT/3/

```
$('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({
    color: '#ff0000',
    flat: true,
    ...
});
```

Even if I disable text selection on the color picker you are still able to select the text around by moving the clicked mouse.

[image]

I could disable text select on the whole page but that would not be nice.

How do I fix this?

Comment: well I cant select text... using FF 20...

Comment: True, works fine with FF but not with Chrome. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want it like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/Praveen16oct90/x6sAT/5/

```
document.getElementById("text_selectable").onmousedown = function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

Give ID for HTML as 'text_selectable' and use it. `<html id="text_selectable">`